# How to get status of auto renew subscription, mainly canceled during sandbox mode?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, subscriptions, auto-renewable

I found multiple suggestion but still stucked. Do not know what I am suppose to get when subscription is canceled. Or what URL I am supposed to give in iTunes to notification. Here is one reponse I got:

```
  "expires_date" = "2017-11-30 14:24:13 Etc/GMT";
        "expires_date_ms" = 1512051853000;
        "expires_date_pst" = "2017-11-30 06:24:13 America/Los_Angeles";
        "is_trial_period" = false;
        "original_purchase_date" = "2017-11-30 14:14:13 Etc/GMT";
        "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1512051253000;
        "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-30 06:14:13 America/Los_Angeles";
        "original_transaction_id" = 1000000356232086;
        "product_id" = "com.demo.demoapp.weeklysubscriptionsssss";
        "purchase_date" = "2017-11-30 14:19:13 Etc/GMT";
        "purchase_date_ms" = 1512051553000;
        "purchase_date_pst" = "2017-11-30 06:19:13 America/Los_Angeles";
        quantity = 1;
        "transaction_id" = 100000fsdfdsf0356233554;
        "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000037061260;
    },
```

What am I supposed to get exactly when an subscription is canceled?

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception about how Apple's subscription status notifications work. Apple will only notify your backend when a subscription has been canceled by customer service, i.e. when a customer contacts Apple and receives refund. When a user cancels normally you will not receive a notification.

In order to detect when someone has cancelled you need to periodically check the receipt against Apple's `/verifyReceipt` endpoint to see if the user intends to renew or not, via the `expiration_intent` field, will tell you why a users subscription expired.

If you are still lost, I recommend reading all of Apple's guide on [subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html). If you are looking for a shortcut you could try something like [RevenueCat](http://www.revenuecat.com/) (disclaimer: it is my pet project).

Comment: Under this case, what is the use of `auto_renew_status` and  `auto_renew_product_id`

Comment: As I know `expiration_intent` is only present when subscription already expired. You need to watch for `auto_renew_status == 0` if you need to know when user voluntarily canceled subscription (e.g. via manage subscriptions in appleID settings) but still has valid subscription until last period expire.